# using python extract string from a list of string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

when i was reading CSV header using following code

```
def  read_header(gram):
    CSV_tag_read = csv.reader(open("Dataset/MALE_Training/"+str(gram)+"/"+str(gram)+".csv","rb"),delimiter='"')
    header=CSV_tag_read.next()
```

The header (The first line of the csv file) will be as follows

`Sample1"('CC', 'CD')"('CD', 'DT')"('DT', 'EX')"('EX', 'IN')"('IN', 'JJ')"('JJ', 'JJR')"('JJR', 'JJS')"('JJS', 'MD')"('MD', 'NN')"('NN', 'NNS')"('NNS', 'PRP')"('PRP', 'RB')"('RB', 'RBR')"('RBR', 'RP')"('RP', 'TO')"('TO', 'VB')"('VB', 'VBD')"('VBD', 'VBG')"('VBG', 'VBN')"('VBN', 'VBP')"('VBP', 'VBZ')"('VBZ', 'WDT')"('WDT', 'WP')"('WP', 'WRB')`

i want my output as list contains

`['Sample1', '(CC, CD)', '(CD, DT)', '(DT, EX)', '(EX, IN)', '(IN, JJ)', '(JJ, JJR)', '(JJR, JJS)', '(JJS, MD)', '(MD, NN)', '(NN, NNS)', '(NNS, PRP)', '(PRP, RB)', '(RB, RBR)', '(RBR, RP)', '(RP, TO)', '(TO, VB)', '(VB, VBD)', '(VBD, VBG)', '(VBG, VBN)', '(VBN, VBP)', '(VBP, VBZ)', '(VBZ, WDT)', '(WDT, WP)', '(WP, WRB)']`

Comment: `eval(a)` should give you a tuple

Comment: My output should be an array contains [TO,RP,TO]

Comment: Is `[Sample2, "(CC, CD" ...` the first line of the csv file?

Comment: What is printed if you do `print(header)` after the `header = ...` line?

Comment: [Sample2, "(CC, CD)", "(CD, DT)", "(DT, EX)", "(EX, IN)", "(IN, JJ)", "(JJ, JJR)", "(JJR, JJS)", "(JJS, MD)", "(MD, NN)", "(NN, NNS)", "(NNS, PRP)", "(PRP, RB)", "(RB, RBR)", "(RBR, RP)", "(RP, TO)", "(TO, VB)", "(VB, VBD)", "(VBD, VBG)", "(VBG, VBN)", "(VBN, VBP)", "(VBP, VBZ)", "(VBZ, WDT)", "(WDT, WP)", "(WP, WRB)"]

Comment: BTW, why do you use `, delimiter='"'`. Remove it, and try it again.

Comment: then output will be Header... ['[Sample2"(\\CC\\', '  \\CD\\)"(\\CD\\', '  \\DT\\)"(\\DT\\', '  \\EX\\)"(\\EX\\', '  \\IN\\)"(\\IN\\', '  \\JJ\\)"(\\JJ\\', '  \\JJR\\)"(\\JJR\\', '  \\JJS\\)"(\\JJS\\', '  \\MD\\)"(\\MD\\', '  \\NN\\)"(\\NN\\', '  \\NNS\\)"(\\NNS\\', '  \\PRP\\)"(\\PRP\\', '  \\RB\\)"(\\RB\\', '  \\RBR\\)"(\\RBR\\', '  \\RP\\)"(\\RP\\', '  \\TO\\)"(\\TO\\', '  \\VB\\)"(\\VB\\', '  \\VBD\\)"(\\VBD\\', '  \\VBG\\)"(\\VBG\\', '  \\VBN\\)"(\\VBN\\', '  \\VBP\\)"(\\VBP\\', '  \\VBZ\\)"(\\VBZ\\', '  \\WDT\\)"(\\WDT\\', '  \\WP\\)"(\\WP\\', ' " WRB)"]']

Comment: ok..i will give u the link..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98lUdXZFzt_VmwtTjFVY0hKRlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See http://asciinema.org/a/6185

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = "('TO', 'RP', 'TO')"
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> b
('TO', 'RP', 'TO')
>>> b[0]
'TO'
```

Or

```
>>> [x.strip("' ") for x in a.strip('()').split(',')]
['TO', 'RP', 'TO']
```

**UPDATED ANSWER** that corresponding to updated question:

```
with open('/path/to/csv-file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='"')
    header = [column.replace("'", "") for column in header]
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use `strip` instead of `replace`. Good answer.

Comment: @shahana.1988 If this answer helped you it would be good to accept it.

Comment: @Kay am the beginner in python